# Trying to join 2 tables

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I'ge got a little problem with joining tables. The first table's structure is

**P_Structure(Structure, Article)**

The second table's structure:

**S_Article(Article, Description)**

Now, Structure and Article have a row in table S_Article (Structure is main thing and article is included). I need to find description for both columns - Structure and Article. Database is made id progress and I'm using ODBC Progress OpenEdge 11.6

@edit

Its almost good but its not pefrect. The tables looks like:

```
S_Article

Article | Description
______________________
AUDI1234 | Car
GLAS3431 | Front Window
TYRE4343 | Michelin super formula
GLAS3433 | Rear window
```

```
P_Structure

Structure | Article
____________________

AUDI1234 | GLAS3431
AUDI1234 | TYRE4343
AUDI1234 | GLAS3433
```

At the finish i would like to get table P_Structure with descriptions for Structure and Article like:

```
Structure | Article | DesciptionStructure | DescriptionArticle
_____________________________________________________________

AUDI1234 | GLAS3431 | Car | Front Window
AUDI1234 | TYRE4343 | Car | Michelin super formula
AUDI1234 | GLAS3433 | Car | Rear window
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value in the "article" column is the same in both tables (i.e. it's a key), you can just join like this:

```
SELECT s.structure, s.article, a.description FROM p_structure s LEFT JOIN s_article a ON s.article =  a.article
```

This will include all the rows from P_structure regardless of if they exist in s_article. If you only want rows in both tables, use "inner join" instead of "left join"

```
SELECT s.structure, s.article, a.description FROM p_structure s INNER JOIN s_article a ON s.article =  a.article
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join your tables as follows:

```
select P_Structure, S_Article.Article, P_Structure.Structure, Description
from P_Structure
join S_Article
on P_Structure.Article = S_Article.Article;
```